# How to fetch data from two different API and map them in expressjs

Tags: node.js, json, express, axios

I am new to Node Express. I know how to do that in PHP but not able to understand in Express JS.

My problem is, I want to fetch Cars Package from two different API or more and create new response by joining their response.

I am using two different API, one is Talixo and Another is IWay.

here are the sample response from them.

sample response from talixo

```
{
      "taxis": [],
      "limousines": [
    {
      "luggage": 3,
      "seats": 3,
      "animals": false,
      "wheelchairs": false,
      "sport_luggage": 2,
      "car_model": "Toyota Prius",
      "children_seat_1": "I/II/III: 9 - 36 kg",
      "children_seat_2": "I/II/III: 9 - 36 kg",
      "id": "34427",
      "color": "black",
      "booking_category": "economy",
      "extended_booking_category": "economy",
      "currency_symbol": "€",
      "currency_code": "EUR",
      "talixo_points": 80,
      "vehicle_type": "limo",
      "included_waiting_time": 45,
      "regular_price": 34.65,
      "discount_price": 34.65,
      "local_price": "",
      "frame_contract": "Integrations",
      "tolls_included": true,
      "gratuity_included": true,
      "search_url": "",
      "image_url": "https://static.talixo.de/images/vehicles/economy.png"
    },
    {
      "luggage": 7,
      "seats": 6,
      "animals": false,
      "wheelchairs": false,
      "sport_luggage": 2,
      "car_model": "VW T5",
      "children_seat_1": "I/II/III: 9 - 36 kg",
      "children_seat_2": "I/II/III: 9 - 36 kg",
      "id": "34429",
      "color": "black",
      "booking_category": "economy",
      "extended_booking_category": "economy_van",
      "currency_symbol": "€",
      "currency_code": "EUR",
      "talixo_points": 80,
      "vehicle_type": "limo",
      "included_waiting_time": 45,
      "regular_price": 46.75,
      "discount_price": 46.75,
      "local_price": "",
      "frame_contract": "Integrations",
      "tolls_included": true,
      "gratuity_included": true,
      "search_url": "",
      "image_url": "https://static.talixo.de/images/vehicles/economy_van.png"
    },
     .......
    ]
}
```

and sample response from iway is here

```
    {
  "result": [
    {
      "price_uid": "aaecf387-dca1-4070-94e9-03f3a40c394b",
      "price": 59.3,
      "price_rub": 4420,
      "reverse_id": null,
      "reverse_price": {
        "price": 0
      },
      "currency": "EUR",
      "service_id": 1,
      "car_class": {
        "car_class_id": 2,
        "title": "Standard",
        "models": [
          "Volkswagen Jetta",
          "Skoda Octavia",
          "Toyota Previa",
          "Audi A4"
        ],
        "photo": "6b6xw3z2m1.png",
        "capacity": 3
      },
      "allowable_subaddress": 3,
      "price_subaddress": 59.3,
      "price_subaddress_rub": 4420,
      "cancellation_time": 6,
      "type": 2,
      "payed_road": false,
      "blackout_date": [],
      "allowable_time": 6,
      "class_services": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "Встреча с табличкой",
          "value": "Да"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "Бесплатное ожидание",
          "value": "20"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "title": "Дополнительный заезд (зависит от настроек заказчика)",
          "value": "Да"
        }
      ],
      "id_custom_price": 100003569,
      "additional_services": [
        {
          "id": 7823,
          "additional_service_id": 2,
          "price": 8.92,
          "name": "Детское кресло “от 0 до 1 года”",
          "description": null,
          "uid": "5d3da41a-fe59-11eb-a2d6-e992f37ca87f",
          "slug": "trans.additional_services.infant_seat.name",
          "default_include": false,
          "currency": "EUR",
          "category": "baby_seat",
          "type": "infant_seat",
          "price_rub": 665
        },
        {
          "id": 7829,
          "additional_service_id": 3,
          "price": 7.14,
          "name": "Детское кресло “от 1 до 3 лет”",
          "description": null,
          "uid": "88833caf-fe59-11eb-a2d6-e992f37ca87f",
          "slug": "trans.additional_services.seat.name",
          "default_include": false,
          "currency": "EUR",
          "category": "baby_seat",
          "type": "seat",
          "price_rub": 532
        },
        {
          "id": 7835,
          "additional_service_id": 4,
          "price": 7.14,
          "name": "Детское кресло “от 3+ лет”",
          "description": null,
          "uid": "a988554c-fe59-11eb-a2d6-e992f37ca87f",
          "slug": "trans.additional_services.booster.name",
          "default_include": false,
          "currency": "EUR",
          "category": "baby_seat",
          "type": "booster",
          "price_rub": 532
        }
      ],
      "additional_services_revert": [
        {
          "id": 7823,
          "additional_service_id": 2,
          "price": 8.92,
          "name": "Детское кресло “от 0 до 1 года”",
          "description": null,
          "uid": "5d3da41a-fe59-11eb-a2d6-e992f37ca87f",
          "slug": "trans.additional_services.infant_seat.name",
          "default_include": false,
          "currency": "EUR",
          "category": "baby_seat",
          "type": "infant_seat"
        },
        {
          "id": 7829,
          "additional_service_id": 3,
          "price": 7.14,
          "name": "Детское кресло “от 1 до 3 лет”",
          "description": null,
          "uid": "88833caf-fe59-11eb-a2d6-e992f37ca87f",
          "slug": "trans.additional_services.seat.name",
          "default_include": false,
          "currency": "EUR",
          "category": "baby_seat",
          "type": "seat"
        },
        {
          "id": 7835,
          "additional_service_id": 4,
          "price": 7.14,
          "name": "Детское кресло “от 3+ лет”",
          "description": null,
          "uid": "a988554c-fe59-11eb-a2d6-e992f37ca87f",
          "slug": "trans.additional_services.booster.name",
          "default_include": false,
          "currency": "EUR",
          "category": "baby_seat",
          "type": "booster"
        }
      ],
      "is_fast_booking": false,
      "flexible_tariff": false,
      "flexible_tariff_agreement": true,
      "price_id": 3020640,
      "minimum_duration": 0,
      "start_place": {
        "place_id": 7891,
        "title": "Undefined",
        "type": 6,
        "type_title": "Others",
        "terminal": [],
        "declension_titles": {
          "nom": null,
          "gen": null,
          "acc": null
        }
      },
      "finish_place": {
        "place_id": 3372,
        "title": "Dubai (center)",
        "type": 9,
        "type_title": "downtown",
        "terminal": [],
        "declension_titles": {
          "nom": null,
          "gen": null,
          "acc": null
        }
      },
      "additional_service_info": {
        "type_place_start": 6,
        "type_place_finish": 6,
        "start_city_id": 395
      }
    },
    {
      "price_uid": "89d1ea54-38a5-40cf-84fd-ba705e6f31ca",
      "price": 103.77,
      "price_rub": 7734,
      "reverse_id": null,
      "reverse_price": {
        "price": 0
      },
      "currency": "EUR",
      "service_id": 1,
      "car_class": {
        "car_class_id": 6,
        "title": "Minivan",
        "models": [
          "Toyota Previa"
        ],
        "photo": "36eg82060g.png",
        "capacity": 5
      },
      "allowable_subaddress": 3,
      "price_subaddress": 103.77,
      "price_subaddress_rub": 7734,
      "cancellation_time": 12,
      "type": 2,
      "payed_road": false,
      "blackout_date": [],
      "allowable_time": 12,
      "class_services": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "title": "Встреча с табличкой",
          "value": "Да"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "title": "Бесплатное ожидание",
          "value": "20"
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "title": "Дополнительный заезд (зависит от настроек заказчика)",
          "value": "Да"
        }
      ],
      "id_custom_price": 100003571,
      "additional_services": [
        {
          "id": 7820,
          "additional_service_id": 2,
          "price": 8.92,
          "name": "Детское кресло “от 0 до 1 года”",
          "description": null,
          "uid": "51434503-fe59-11eb-a2d6-e992f37ca87f",
          "slug": "trans.additional_services.infant_seat.name",
          "default_include": false,
          "currency": "EUR",
          "category": "baby_seat",
          "type": "infant_seat",
          "price_rub": 665
        },
        {
          "id": 7826,
          "additional_service_id": 3,
          "price": 7.14,
          "name": "Детское кресло “от 1 до 3 лет”",
          "description": null,
          "uid": "7db22146-fe59-11eb-a2d6-e992f37ca87f",
          "slug": "trans.additional_services.seat.name",
          "default_include": false,
          "currency": "EUR",
          "category": "baby_seat",
          "type": "seat",
          "price_rub": 532
        },
        {
          "id": 7832,
          "additional_service_id": 4,
          "price": 7.14,
          "name": "Детское кресло “от 3+ лет”",
          "description": null,
          "uid": "9f932316-fe59-11eb-a2d6-e992f37ca87f",
          "slug": "trans.additional_services.booster.name",
          "default_include": false,
          "currency": "EUR",
          "category": "baby_seat",
          "type": "booster",
          "price_rub": 532
        }
      ],
      "additional_services_revert": [
        {
          "id": 7820,
          "additional_service_id": 2,
          "price": 8.92,
          "name": "Детское кресло “от 0 до 1 года”",
          "description": null,
          "uid": "51434503-fe59-11eb-a2d6-e992f37ca87f",
          "slug": "trans.additional_services.infant_seat.name",
          "default_include": false,
          "currency": "EUR",
          "category": "baby_seat",
          "type": "infant_seat"
        },
        {
          "id": 7826,
          "additional_service_id": 3,
          "price": 7.14,
          "name": "Детское кресло “от 1 до 3 лет”",
          "description": null,
          "uid": "7db22146-fe59-11eb-a2d6-e992f37ca87f",
          "slug": "trans.additional_services.seat.name",
          "default_include": false,
          "currency": "EUR",
          "category": "baby_seat",
          "type": "seat"
        },
        {
          "id": 7832,
          "additional_service_id": 4,
          "price": 7.14,
          "name": "Детское кресло “от 3+ лет”",
          "description": null,
          "uid": "9f932316-fe59-11eb-a2d6-e992f37ca87f",
          "slug": "trans.additional_services.booster.name",
          "default_include": false,
          "currency": "EUR",
          "category": "baby_seat",
          "type": "booster"
        }
      ],
      "is_fast_booking": false,
      "flexible_tariff": false,
      "flexible_tariff_agreement": true,
      "price_id": 3020641,
      "minimum_duration": 0,
      "start_place": {
        "place_id": 7891,
        "title": "Undefined",
        "type": 6,
        "type_title": "Others",
        "terminal": [],
        "declension_titles": {
          "nom": null,
          "gen": null,
          "acc": null
        }
      },
      "finish_place": {
        "place_id": 3372,
        "title": "Dubai (center)",
        "type": 9,
        "type_title": "downtown",
        "terminal": [],
        "declension_titles": {
          "nom": null,
          "gen": null,
          "acc": null
        }
      },
      "additional_service_info": {
        "type_place_start": 6,
        "type_place_finish": 6,
        "start_city_id": 395
      }
    }
  ],
  "error": null
}
```

and i want to create my own response from their data like.

```
{
                    'activityid': "",
                    'availabletime': "",
                    'carimageurl': "",
                    'freecanceltime': "",
                    'freewaittime': "",
                    'inclusivedesc': "",
                    'hvreferralid': "",
                    'hvreferraltype': "",
                    'maxluggagecount' => "",
                    'maxpassangerscount': "",
                    'originprice': "",
                    'originpriceformatted': "",
                    'packageId': "",
                    'serviceproviderid': "",
                    'serviceprovidername': "Talixo or Iway",
                    'vehicleid': "",
                    'carname': "",
                    'vehicletype': "",
                    'vehicleremarks': "or Similar",
}
```

this is what i have done so far in express controller

```
        const httpStatus = require('http-status');
    const pick = require('../utils/pick');
    const catchAsync = require('../utils/catchAsync');
    const axios = require('axios');
    const Talixoapi = 'somekey'
    
    const searchCars = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    
        try {
    
            const talixoheaders = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Partner': Talixoapi
            }
    
            const iwayheaders = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
            }
            
            const payload = {
                "start_point": req.body.start_point,
                "end_point": req.body.end_point,
                "start_time_date": req.body.start_time_date,
                "start_time_time": req.body.start_time_time,
                "passengers": req.body.passengers,
                "sport_luggage": req.body.sport_luggage,
                "animals": req.body.animals,
                "luggage": req.body.luggage
            }

//talixo api request

            const { data } = await axios.post(`https://talixo.com/en/mapi/v3/vehicles/booking_query/`, payload, {
                headers: talixoheaders
            })

//iway api request    
            const { iwaydata } = await axios.get(`https://sandbox.iway.io/transnextgen/v3/prices?user_id=747853&lang=en&currency=EUR&start_place_point=24.9178231%2C55.0111167&finish_place_point=25.259478%2C55.3229291`, {
                headers: iwayheaders
            })
            
            res.json(data)
        }
        catch (err) {
    
            res.send(err)
    
        }
    
    });
    
    
    module.exports = {
        searchCars
    }
```

i don't know what to do next here in controller.

what i understand till now is that, i need to create own json array by using foreach for every results and then merge all the arrays.

one more issue, i don't know why but when i use

const { iwaydata } or const { talixodata }, it gives blank result, but when i use const { data }, it works fine.

and this is what i have done till now by following suggestions from @sangam rajpara.

```
const searchCars = catchAsync(async (req, res) => {

try {

    const talixoheaders = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Partner': Talixoapi
    }

    const iwayheaders = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ***************'
    }
    
    const payload = {
        "start_point": req.body.start_point,
        "end_point": req.body.end_point,
        "start_time_date": req.body.start_time_date,
        "start_time_time": req.body.start_time_time,
        "passengers": req.body.passengers,
        "sport_luggage": req.body.sport_luggage,
        "animals": req.body.animals,
        "luggage": req.body.luggage
    }

    const { data: talixoData } = await axios.post(`https://talixo.com/en/mapi/v3/vehicles/booking_query/`, payload, {
        headers: talixoheaders
    })

    const { data: iwayData } = await axios.get(`https://sandbox.iway.io/transnextgen/v3/prices?user_id=1863&lang=en&currency=USD&start_place_point=24.9178231%2C55.0111167&finish_place_point=25.259478%2C55.3229291`, {
        headers: iwayheaders
    })

    const taxiresults = [];

    if (talixoData.taxis.length) {
        talixoData.taxis.forEach(function (item) {
            arrcars = {};
            arrcars["carname"] = item.car_model;
            arrcars["originprice"] = item.regular_price;
            arrcars["packageId"] = item.id;
            arrcars["image"] = item.image_url;
            arrcars["vendor"] = "Talixo";
            arrcars["vehicleremarks"] = "Or Similar";
            taxiresults.push(arrcars);
        });
    }
    
    if (talixoData.limousines.length){
        talixoData.limousines.forEach(function (item) {
            arrcars = {};
            arrcars["carname"] = item.car_model;
            arrcars["originprice"] = item.regular_price;
            arrcars["packageId"] = item.id;
            arrcars["image"] = item.image_url;
            arrcars["vendor"] = "Talixo";
            arrcars["vehicleremarks"] = "Or Similar";
            taxiresults.push(arrcars);
        });
    }

    if (iwayData.result.length) {
        iwayData.result.forEach(function (item) {
            var imgsrc = "https://iwayex.com/images/cars/";
            arrcars = {};
            arrcars["carname"] = item.car_class.models[0];
            arrcars["originprice"] = item.price;
            arrcars["packageId"] = item.price_uid;
            arrcars["image"] = imgsrc + item.car_class.photo;
            arrcars["vendor"] = "iway Transfers";
            arrcars["vehicleremarks"] = "Or Similar";
            taxiresults.push(arrcars);
        });
    }
   
    res.json(taxiresults)
}
catch (err) {

    res.send(err)

}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Axios, you receive API response data in the data key of the response object.

What you can do is.

```
//talixo api request

        const { data: talixoData } = await axios.post(`https://talixo.com/en/mapi/v3/vehicles/booking_query/`, payload, {
            headers: talixoheaders
        })

//iway api request    
        const { data: iwayData } = await axios.get(`https://sandbox.iway.io/transnextgen/v3/prices?user_id=747853&lang=en&currency=EUR&start_place_point=24.9178231%2C55.0111167&finish_place_point=25.259478%2C55.3229291`, {
            headers: iwayheaders
        })
```

If you are new to javascript what I did is destructured the object and renamed key data.

Comment: i understand this now, but how to use foreach here in both these api responses and create my custom json array using the keys i above mentioned.. hope you understand what i want here.

Comment: You can map one of those array and add other array's values in the array objects or else you can create empty array push custom value in the end of foreach you'll have your own array which you can send in api response.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i followed and updated that in question but how can i handle error on both those api's separately. i mean, if talixo or iway gives some bad response then how to handle that. i mean if one of these gives bad response, it still should fetch data from another source. it would be great, if you can help me in organizing the code in better way.